# Keeping a backend function open in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, flask

So I have a pretty simple python function sitting in the backend as follows:

```
def iterator():
    for i in range(1000):
        random_var = randrange(1000)
        return jsonify({
            "random_var" : random_var,
        })
        time.sleep(4)
```

When I run this function standalone, it runs for well a 1000 times very slowly generating a random number every 4 seconds. What I want is to connect this to html frontend via javascript and the code for that is as follows:

```
var Output_value  = document.getElementById('Output_value');
 
$(function() {
    $('#exe-btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/display/',
            success: function(data) {Output_value.innerHTML = data['random_var'];} });
     }   
    
    );
});
```

This does work but not exactly as I expect it to.

[Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWXor.png)

It displays the value once and then just stops and doesn't display it again unless I press the button again.

**What I've researched so far:**

The two potential candidates that I found to solve this included the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions in jquery, however the flaw with that approach is that they require the execution of the backend python function again and again, while what I require is that function to be executed only once.

**What I want it to do**

I want the backend `iterator()` to be executed only once and then the values of it to be returned to js so that the *newest* value is displayed on the html frontend and taking the place of the previous value.

What is happening right now is that the function in the backend is executed upon click but it stops streaming the output after returning one result.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're trying to do here is going to be architecturally possible without either (as you have already found) making separate HTTP requests and keeping some sort of state on the server, or otherwise resorting to something like WebSockets. The `success` handler for `$.ajax` will not fire until the HTTP response is complete - you can't just keep that connection open and continue to emit values (again, without WebSockets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is using websockets as Sergey said. The architecture for that is pretty simple though.

Keep an id in the html which will be used by the javascript to output the data it receives from the flask server. The flask server will use socket io and the javascript file will also use socket. The way it will work is that once the execute button on the frontend is pressed, the js calls an event in the backend which will receive it and then transmit out the data that you want to transmit. This is what the html code looks like:

```
  <div class="Output">
    <table>
      <th ><h2>Python Library Output:</h2></th>
      <th id="Output_value"> </th>
    </table>
  </div>
 
 
 
<div class= "execute_button">
    <button id="exe-btn">Execute</button>
</div>
```

The `exe-btn` here is what we bind to jquery, which will call the module execution event in the backend. The JS code:

```
//Creating the event for execution of backend iterator script
//Setting up the event to be executed when the execute button is clicked and not otherwise
$(function() {
    $('#exe-btn').click(function(){
    socket.emit('module_trigger', {
    data: 'Module event triggered'
    })
     }   
    );
});


socket.on( 'module_trigger_stream', function( msg ) {
    console.log( 'Response 2')
    console.log(msg['add'])
    Output_value.innerHTML = msg['add']
    //console.log(msg['message'])
  }
);
```

Now the final step is to set up the handlers in the backend and also the method for creating the data. I use a simple random number generator which keeps emitting values after some time:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template 
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
import math
import time
#module imports
from random import randrange
import json
 

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder ='templates/')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
 
socketio = SocketIO(app)

 
@socketio.on('module_trigger')
def handle_module_trigger(jsons, methods=['GET','POST']):
    print('Trigger successfully executed')
    print(str(jsons))
    for i in range(1000):
            random_var = randrange(1000)
            time.sleep(4)
            print("The random variable is " + str(random_var))
            out = {'add' : str(random_var)}
            socketio.emit('module_trigger_stream',out)
 
 

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def render_output(): 
    return render_template("index.html" )
     


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)
```